# Copy Dynamic Range to Another Workbook based on cell value using VBA

Tags: excel, vba

[image: test]I am trying to copy a dynamic range(dyna) from activesheet and paste it to a new workbook located in "E:\1b\", file name based on cell value(J7).

Below is the formula in the dynamic range:

> dyna = "=OFFSET(Sheet1!$D$6,0,0,COUNTA(Sheet1!$D:$J),7)"

I need help to do it.

here is code I have

```
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
  ThisWorkbook.Activate
  ActiveSheet.dyna.Copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)
  wb.Activate
  Application.DisplayAlerts = False
  wb.SaveAs "E:\1b\" & Range("J7").Value & ".xlsx", 
  FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
  wb.Close "E:\1b\" & Range("J7").Value & ".xlsx"
  Application.DisplayAlerts = True

End Sub
```

Comment: SO will help you resolve specific failure of your code. Your code will fail because of a specific line causing a run-time error, or because the result is not what you expect. Is your code causing a run-time error or is it not doing what you expect? Need to see where `dyna` is assigned as well. Providing the complete procedure will be helpful.

Comment: `Range("dyna")`?

Comment: SmileyFtW , please see picture in edited question.

Comment: @lucky1987, follow BigBen piece of advice and get rid of `"E:\1b\" & Range("J7").Value & ".xlsx"` after `wb.Close`

Comment: @HTH, I used Range("dyna")... but it didn't work, please suggest me any other

Comment: _"didn't work"_ is too little of a information...please update your question with current code and issue

Comment: what happens? don't leave me hanging like this!

Comment: @HTH, I am unable to explain, sorry for that, Please simply tell me how to copy a dynamic range to another workbook by cell value.

Comment: _simply_ googling _"how to copy a dynamic range to another workbook by cell value"_  you come to [these results](https://www.google.com/search?q=copy+a+dynamic+range+to+another+workbook+by+cell+value&ie=&oe=). If you want help in debugging your code you have to _simply_ describe what error your code throw and which line is throwing it

Comment: Run-time error 1004 appears
and highlight code that i bold....also opens a new blank workbook

`Sub copy()
Set wb = Workbooks.Add
ThisWorkbook.Activate`
**ActiveSheet.Range("dyna").copy Before:=wb.Sheets(1)**
`wb.Activate
Application.DisplayAlerts = False
wb.SaveAs "E:\1b\" & Range("J7").Value & ".xlsx", FileFormat:=xlOpenXMLWorkbook, ReadOnlyRecommended:=False, CreateBackup:=False
wb.Close "E:\1b\" & Range("J7").Value & ".xlsx"
Application.DisplayAlerts = True
End Sub`